# Can a gear motor w encoder be 60 ft away from controller?

Tags: dc-motor

This is my first time posting so please forgive any ignorance that may come across.

I'm considering hooking up two gear motors (Devantech 24V, 49:1 Gear Motor w/ Encoder) to a motor drive (MD49 - Dual 24 Volt 5 Amp H Bridge Motor Drive). I'd like the gear motor to be about 60 feet away from the motor drive, connected through wiring.

Would this distance cause any issues with feedback/control etc through voltage or current losses?

Also, I assume that the motor controller will cause one motor to go CW and the other CCW?

Links:
http://www.robotshop.com/en/devantech-2 ... coder.html

http://www.robotshop.com/en/devantech-m ... river.html

Thanks in advance,
Radek

Comment: There is no such thing as "current loss"; KCL holds true regardless of the length of the conductor.

Comment: It's true that there is no such thing as current loss but isn't OP referring to the lower current due to higher overall line impedance?

Comment: There is current loss if you consider the capacitance towards ground along the conductor :-). But it should be negligible.

Comment: I think he may be referring to power loss over the long line ->more resistance, more power dissipation.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The application is a tennis product I build called the [PickupWall](http://www.pickupwall.com) that collects balls from the back of a court and feeds them back to a ball machine. The motors are used to drive a small auger in the ball track that feeds the balls towards the middle of the court.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your answer is pretty straightforward. The driver can drive the motor at this distance, as long as you make sure to use reasonably thick wire. 20 ga ought to do.

But. Running the motor will require careful shielding of your cable, since the PWM noise will be radiating like crazy if you don't. Twisted pair for the motor drive at least, and probably shielded twisted pair.

The encoder is a big maybe. A lot depends on what the frequency is of the encoder steps at full speed. Data sheet says a maximum of 7000 shaft rpm with 980 steps per revolution. That's 114 kHz. The encoder data sheet says that these are open-collector drivers. This is not usually great for these distances and frequencies. I think you'll need to buffer the signals using some sort of differential driver, such as an RS485 driver. This would mean that you'd have to provide a small (1 IC plus a regulator)interface board at the encoder end of the cable, which would need a regulator to drop the +12 supplied by the controller board to +5 for the drivers. You'd also need a small (1 IC plus a regulator) receiver board at the controller.  And you'll need to go from 4 wires to 6, with one twisted pair for the power and ground, and a twisted pair for each of the encoder channels.

The driver will drive each motor in either direction independently. Actually, you can select rotation direction for a given command direction simply by reversing the motor leads. Be aware, however, that if you try to reverse direction at any real speed, you'll hit current limit on the driver. You'll need to provide a ramp command to the motors (that is, a gradual change in speed command) in that case.

Also be aware that, with these motor/encoders, you will have a very great deal of trouble trying to maintain a fixed shaft angle. At best, you'll get a small oscillation of +/- 1 encoder step around your desired position. At worst, it will be larger than this, with considerable power being dissipated in the motor. These motor/encoder sets are excellent for maintaining a constant speed of rotation - fixed position, not so much.

If you're thinking of a CNC-type positioning setup, you're better off going with steppers.

Comment: I will second the suggestion of using differential signaling to control a small micro at the other end. Will probably save you lots of headaches.

Comment: Using the differential signalling will actually require 8 wires. One twisted pair for the motor. Two twisted pairs for the encoder channels A & B. One additional twisted pair for the supply leads to power the small interface board at the end of the cable.

Comment: Not if he includes a local regulator. Which, considering the low power requirements for driving two channels, is perfectly reasonable. I've edited.

Comment: The application is a tennis product I build called the [PickupWall](http://www.pickupwall.com) that collects balls from the back of a court and feeds them back to a ball machine. The motors are used to drive a small auger in the ball track that feeds the balls towards the middle of the court. I've already tried using 120VAC 100 and 60 RPM gear motors but they are under-powered. I'm looking for something that will turn constant speed at ~100-120 RPM with a torque of 100 oz-in at minimum. Since the two motors are 60 feet apart, I could place the driver in the middle of the court, so 30ft.